# (1 of 11: Numberlink) What is Pyramid Cult's Favorite Activity?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

<sub>*Dear PSE users and moderators,

I’m new here in PSE, but I really need your help. There was this person who gave me a black envelope consisting 10+1 pages of puzzles, and also a scribble saying: “Find our favorites and you will be accepted to join our ‘pyramid cult’. Feel free to ask for help from your beloved friends on PSE. They will surely guide you into all the truth.” I’m also a newbie on grid puzzles, so, could you please give me any hint to solve these? It’s getting harder and harder later on..

- athin*</sub>

<sub>**Next page:** [#2 Moon-or-Sun](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86623/28719) | **Jump to the last page:** [#END Meta](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/87001/28719)</sub>

---

[image: Numberlink]

> **Rules:**
>
> 1. Connect pairs of the same numbers with a continuous line.
> 2. Lines go through the center of the cells, moving in perpendicular direction with one of the cell sides, or changing direction, and never twice through the same cell.
> 3. Lines cannot cross, branch off, or go through the cells with numbers.

---

<sup>*Special thanks to **chaotic_iak** for testing this puzzle series!*</sup>

Comment: I'm planning to post each page every $36$ hours, hope you guys find some funs for these $2$ weeks! ^^

Comment: Retreating to the study to practice Moon-or-Sun...

Comment: The lines go perpendicular to the board sides, not parallel.

Comment: @aschepler Nice catch! I'll update accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Completed numberlink

> [image]

Their favourite activity

> is spelt by the unvisited cells, which spell **SURFING**.

Reasoning

> First of all, both the 6 and the 7 need to pass through to the lower part of the board. There are only two spaces they can use to get there.
>
>  [image]
>
>  The 7 cannot use the left-hand side without blocking the 6 entirely. Even going around the 6 doesn't help as there is no room for the 6 to pass.
>
>  [image]
>
>  So the 6 must pass through the left and the 7 through the right.
>
>  [image]
>
>  There is only one way to get to the 3 now, so fill that in.
>
>  [image]
>
>  The 1 must go around the 7 in the corner in order to not block access to it.
>
>
>  [image]
>  The most direct line toward the 7 blocks none of the remaining free cells, so we can fill that in without blocking any of the other lines.
>
>  [image]
>
>  There is only one way to get to the 4 without blocking the 1.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Only one way to get to the 1 now.
>
>  [image]
>
>  The 2 cannot block the 6 in the corner, so it must go around it.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Only one way to get to the 5.
>
>  [image]
>
>  The most direct line to the 6 is the only way to keep a line open for the 2.
>
>  [image]
>
>  One line left to fill, and only one way to do it.

Comment: darn it! sniped +1

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Mwe he he!

Comment: getting 30 rep in 1 minute is IMPRESSIVE

Comment: You got it right, Jafe (and better luck next time, O.K. :D)! Checkmark will be awarded in several hours.

Comment: I think you can go around the 6 without blocking it.  Just go straight up to the cell marked 'S', instead of out to the center.  You will end up blocking 3 though, so the solution is still to use the other connection.

Comment: @Taemyr Wow, you're right. How'd I miss that? I'll fix the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

the finished numberlink

> [image]

answer:

> unvisited grids spell SURFING (thanks @jafe)