# (9 of 11: Shikaku) What is Pyramid Cult's Favorite Stationeries?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

<sub>*Dear PSE users and moderators,

I’m new here in PSE, but I really need your help. There was this person who gave me a black envelope consisting 10+1 pages of puzzles, and also a scribble saying: “Find our favorites and you will be accepted to join our ‘pyramid cult’. Feel free to ask for help from your beloved friends on PSE. They will surely guide you into all the truth.” I’m also a newbie on grid puzzles, so, could you please give me any hint to solve these? It’s getting harder and harder later on..

- athin*</sub>

<sub>**Jump to the first page:** [#1 Numberlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86563/28719) | **Previous page:** [#8 Ripple Effect](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86891/28719) | **Next page:** [#10 Nurikabe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86979/28719)</sub>

---

[image]

> **Rules:**
>
> 1. Divide the grid into triangles or quadrilaterals with the numbers in the cells.
> 2. Each triangle or quadrilateral is to contain only one number showing the number of cells in the triangle or quadrilateral.

---

<sup>*Special thanks to **chaotic_iak** for testing this puzzle series!*</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The finished puzzle

> [image]

Answer: (thanks Deusovi!)

> Take the middles of the odd-sized "line" sections to get HOLDERS.

Comment: Noice! This is correct! :D

Comment: Clearly it should have been that triangle-shaped ruler thingy.