# (10 of 11: Nurikabe) What is Pyramid Cult's Favorite Topic?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

<sub>*Dear PSE users and moderators,

I’m new here in PSE, but I really need your help. There was this person who gave me a black envelope consisting 10+1 pages of puzzles, and also a scribble saying: “Find our favorites and you will be accepted to join our ‘pyramid cult’. Feel free to ask for help from your beloved friends on PSE. They will surely guide you into all the truth.” I’m also a newbie on grid puzzles, so, could you please give me any hint to solve these? It’s getting harder and harder later on..

- athin*</sub>

<sub>**Jump to the first page:** [#1 Numberlink](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86563/28719) | **Previous page:** [#9 Shikaku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/86939/28719) | **Next page:** [#END Meta](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/87001/28719)</sub>

---

[image]

> **Rules:**
>
> 1. Shade the cells under the following rules.
> 2. You cannot shade cells containing numbers.
> 3. A number tells the number of continuous white cells. Each area of white cells contains exactly one number in it and they are separated by shaded cells.
> 4. The shaded cells are linked to be a continuous wall.
> 5. Shaded cells cannot be linked to be 5-in-a-row cells.

---

<sup>*Special thanks to **chaotic_iak** for testing this puzzle series!*</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer is here:

> [image]

Favourite topic:

> Anagram of yellow area (wall) is FASHION

Welp... I'm too stupid and blind to the apparent... jafe has found out the same answer can be obtained by

> reading the letters left-to-right, row by row. Thanks @jafe!

Comment: Not need to anagram, you can just read the letters left-to-right, row by row :)

Comment: Good job! :D Now it's time for the meta part~ ;)